# Error: unreachable statement en métodos de la misma clase

Tags: java

Obtengo el error "`Error: unreachable statement setPrevAns(f)`" al ejecutar el siguiente código. La función `factorial()`, que se activa cuando el objeto `scan` recibe el comando `/factorial <número>`, hace lo siguiente:
Si el comando contiene la cadena "`ans`" después de `/factorial` , calcula el factorial de la variable `prevAns`, número con el valor de la última respuesta calculada. 
Si no contiene "`ans`", simplemente computa el factorial del número escrito después de `/factorial` y guarda el resultado en `prevAns` 
Ejemplo:

```
/factorial 4
24
/factorial ans
620448401733239439360000
```

*(Devuelve factorial de la respuesta previa, es decir, 24)*

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.BigInteger;


class server {  
    public static String prevAns;
    public static void setprevAns(Object obj) {
        prevAns = obj.toString();
    }

    public static BigInteger factorial(String n) {
        if(n.contains("ans")) {
            return factorial(n.replace("ans", ""));
        } else {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(n.replace("/factorial ", ""));
            BigInteger f = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
            for(int x = 1; x <= num; x++) {
                f = f.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(x));
            }
            return f;
            setprevAns(f);
        }       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Networking objects and scanner
        ServerSocket SS = new ServerSocket(52656);
        Socket S = SS.accept();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(S.getInputStream());
        PrintStream P = new PrintStream(S.getOutputStream());

        String message;

        // Gets the message and responds to it
        while(true) {
            message = scan.nextLine();
            if(scan.hasNext()) {                

                if(message.startsWith("/factorial ")) {
                    P.println(factorial(message));
                }

            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En el método *factorial* tienes una sentencia `setprevAns(f);` **después** de *return*. Obviamente no se puede ejecutar. Revisa la lógica del método y, probablemente, debes mover `setprevAns(f);` antes del return.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Funciona correctamente